# Silverlight - Run Method at Application start on server side

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight-Application which is hosted in a ASP.NET-Site. Now, I need to execute something at the first start of the application (run code for update database). I am searching the right place to do this.
Can anybody help me where I have to put this code? - Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add to the `Startup` event in your Application class, e.g.

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    { 
       ... startup code here
    }
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Note that this runs on the client side - not the server side. Code in your silverlight application does not run on the server.

If your code has to run on the server, host your silverlight control in an aspx page and override the page's `Page_Load` event to execute code BEFORFE the silverlight client is sent to the browser.

Comment: Or have the `Application_Startup` code call a WCF service on the server if it has to happen after code download.

Comment: Good comment - all depends on what order you need things to happen in.